# Endless loop while showing dates

Tags: php, while-loop, strtotime

Suddenly without any changes within the code, following part is running within an endless loop (for more than two years it worked very well):

```
$date = date("d.m.Y l", strtotime($supplyDate));
$end = date("d.m.Y l",strtotime("+1 months"));

if(!empty($date_dif)) {
$i = 1;
// PATCH one day minus
$date = date("d.m.Y l", strtotime($date)-(86400));
while (strtotime($date)<strtotime($end)) {
    $date = date("d.m.Y l", strtotime($date)+(86400));
    $day = date("l", strtotime($date));
    if($day == "Saturday" && (intval($isSaturdayOpen) == 0 && intval($date_dif) == 1)){ continue;}
    if($day == "Sunday" && (intval($isSundayOpen) == 0 && intval($date_dif) == 1)){ continue;}

    $tab_content .= '<option value="'.strtotime($date).'">'.utf8_encode(strftime('%d.%m.%Y %A',strtotime($date))).'</option>';

    $i++;
    if($i==10){
        break;
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: Can you just add some echos to the code to see what the state of the vars are?  If instance, if "i never equals 10"

Comment: why do you need all these conversions from string to timestamp back and force?

Comment: I just ran the code, unedited on my server, and it worked fine. Well, I set the to $supplyDate='2015-10-01'; and turned off the IF condition.  But other than that, I changed nothing.  It echoed back dates up till Thursday the 8th, and stopped on it's own.

Comment: does anyone has a bit time to get a deep look into my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Wierd but you can use one trick on end of your code:

```
if((int)$i===10){
     break;    /* You could also write 'break 1;' here. */
}
```

Just in case that if `$i` is not recognized by type you can convert like integer and compare with integer.

I can't find other problem here.